# How to exclude posts with no images in a wordpress query_post function?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The query below runs a featured carousel on my site. I want the carousel to only display post that contain an image. I've searched everywhere and cannot find a solution. Please help!

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'ad_listing', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'rand'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same thing while developing my own theme.
This is how I solved it.

Start by adding the featured image capability in your functions.php.

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
```

This allows you to select a featured image for each post.

With the featured image function available you can use the following function to detect if a post has a featured image...in loop form:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'ad_listing'
);
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { //For featured images
            //For post images/attachments
                ob_start();
                the_id(); 
                $postID = ob_get_clean(); 
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => 1,
                    'order'=> 'ASC',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'post_parent' => $postID,
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment'
                );
                $images =& get_children($args);

                if ( empty($images) ) {
                    //What to do without images
                }
                else {
                    //What to do with images
                }
        }
    endwhile;
else :
    //What happens when no posts are found
endif;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but not all post have a featured image. Its more of an attachment. I apologize if i did not specify. Also, it is picking up other post_type's other than just ad_listing

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I would include the "has_post_thumbnail() inside the post loop, but I would customize it slightly to only get your post type. I'll update my answer

Comment: This is soo close i can feel it, but im still getting post with no images :(

Comment: Just updated the answer with another method. I tested it on my wordpress and it seems to work.

Comment: thank you everyone. I found the solution here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_children-inside-custom-loop. I placed this code inside my while have posts() $files = get_children(
array(
 'post_parent' => $post->ID,
 'post_status' => 'inherit',
 'post_type' => 'attachment',
 'post_mime_type' => 'image',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'orderby' => 'menu_order'
 )
);
if($files) { ...do something}

Comment: Seems like they are very similar. Thank you mike for your help. Looks like your solution works as well!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that using query_posts. You'll have to do it in the loop.

Look at `get_children()` and especially the example of how to [Show the first image associated with the post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children).